# C LUA API - Get table value at index

Tags: c, lua, lua-table

Assuming the following lua code:

```
local FooTable={ ["FooKey"]="FooValue" }
```

The index of `"FooValue"` is `"FooKey"`. So I can access it like this without any issues (Assuming FooTable is on top of the stack.):

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, "FooKey");
```

When I try something like this:

```
local FooTable={ "FooValue" }
```

I would assume that index of `"FooValue"` is `"1"`. But the following gives me a `nil` return.

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, "1");
```

Is there a special approach to accessing numeric keys in tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second case the index is number one, not a string "1".

One way of getting the first element is using the following function:

```
void lua_rawgeti (lua_State *L, int index, int key);
```

Another way is to push a key on the stack and call:

```
void lua_gettable (lua_State *L, int index);
```

The first way will NOT trigger metamethods, the second one may.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The end result would look like this:

    lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
    lua_gettable(L, -2);